# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'agent_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting errors because of the foreign key field. I have two Models ( Agent, Post ). I cannot get the user's primary key to be saved as a foreign key in the posts table. I can insert the data manually, and it links with the parent table, but when the user inserts from the form in view, it gives me that error any help?

**Agent**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Agent extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

**Post**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Agent::class);
    }
}
```

And here is my method in the controller to save the data.

```
public function savepost(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->description = $request->description;
    $post->type = $request->type;
    $saved = $post->save();
    
    if ($saved) {
        return back()->with('success', 'New post has been added successfuly');
    } else {
        return back()->with('fail', 'Something went wrong , try again later');
    }
}
```

Comment: If it’s the Auth user , add agent_id => auth()->user()->id

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Attempt to read property "id" on null

Comment: I thing, because you modified model user to model agent, so you can't use auth()->user()->id. may be you should modified table name too.

Comment: is auth () - user - id the only method to get the primary key of the user?

Comment: it’s easy and direct there’s also User facade

Answer (score 0):

in my think, `Post` model should have `agent_id` and when create new `Post`, `agent_id` is required with current `user->id`. so it seems to be added `agent_id` in new `Post` object.

```
...
use Auth;
...


public function savepost(Request $request){
    $post = new Post ;
    $post->title = $request->title ;
    $post->description = $request->description ;
    $post->type = $request->type;
    $post->agent_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $saved = $post->save();
   if($saved){
     return back()->with('success','New post has been added successfuly');
 }else{
     return back()->with('fail' , 'Something went wrong , try again later');
 }
}
```

Comment: post model already have agent_id column but auth::user()->id is not working , it returns null